Shiny app working on local device but not on shinyapps.io
I have an interactive map that I have created using shiny apps and it works on my local device. When I try to deploy to shinyapps.io using the deployApp() function i receive "An error has occurred. The application failed to start. exit status 1" on my browser. Through looking at the logs that correspond at least one issue comes up"2024-08-29T16:27:06.890581+00:00 shinyapps[12555547]: Error in leafletOutput("map") : could not find function "leafletOutput" I have updated leaflet and it is libraried inside my code.
Using a different method - When I have the app running locally and I try to "publish", I receive this error
── Preparing for deployment:heavy_check_mark: Deploying "ShinyApp" using server: shinyapps.io / username: XXXX

Error in quartoInspect():! Failed to run quarto inspect against your content:

ERROR: C./license_data.rds is not a valid Quarto inputdocumentBacktrace:▆ 
└─rsconnect::deployApp(...)
└─rsconnect:::appMetadata(...)
└─rsconnect:::inferQuartoInfo(...)
└─rsconnect:::quartoInspect(appDir = appDir, appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc)
└─cli::cli_abort(...)
└─rlang::abort(...)

Execution halted.

I have updated the corresponding packages and tried a variety of workarounds.
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(htmltools)
library(rsconnect)

setwd("./ShinyApp")
#shiny app for total fishing license sales
# Load and preprocess data
postal_areas <- readRDS("postal_areas.rds")
postal_areas_long <- as.data.table(readRDS("postal_areas_long.rds"))
setkey(postal_areas_long, CFSAUID, Year)

# Simplify geometries
postal_areas_simple <- st_simplify(postal_areas, dTolerance = 0.01)

# Create a spatial index
postal_areas_simple <- st_make_valid(postal_areas_simple)
spatial_index <- st_cast(postal_areas_simple, "MULTIPOLYGON")

# Pre-compute color palette
color_palette <- colorNumeric("YlOrRd", domain = range(postal_areas_simple$F2021, na.rm = TRUE))

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      #map {height: 50vh !important;}
      .title-container {text-align: center; font-size: 24px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
      .title-container h1 {margin: 0;}
    "))
  ),
  div(class = "title-container",
      h1("Fishing License Holders in Ontario")
  ),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  plotlyOutput("fishingPlot")
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected_area <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  drawn_polygon <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  # Render initial map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = mean(st_bbox(postal_areas_simple)[c(1,3)]),
              lat = mean(st_bbox(postal_areas_simple)[c(2,4)]),
              zoom = 6) %>%
      addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup = "drawn_polygon",
        polylineOptions = FALSE,
        polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(shapeOptions = drawShapeOptions(fillOpacity = 0.3, color = "#1E90FF")),
        circleOptions = FALSE,
        markerOptions = FALSE,
        circleMarkerOptions = FALSE,
        rectangleOptions = FALSE,
        editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions())
      ) %>%
      addControl(
        html = tags$div(
          id = "summary",
          style = "background-color: white; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;",
          HTML("<strong>Area Summary:</strong><br>No area selected")
        ),
        position = "topright"
      )
  })
  
  # Add polygons incrementally
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = postal_areas_simple,
                  fillColor = ~color_palette(F2021),
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = "#BDBDC3",
                  layerId = ~CFSAUID,
                  popup = ~paste(
                    "<strong>Forward Sortation Code:</strong>", CFSAUID, "<br>",
                    "<strong>Province:</strong>", PRNAME, "<br>",
                    "<strong>Fishing License Holders (2021):</strong>", F2021, "<br>",
                    "<strong>Area (km²):</strong>", round(area_km2, 2)
                  ),
                  label = ~lapply(paste(
                    "<strong>Forward Sortation Code:</strong>", CFSAUID, "<br>",
                    "<strong>Fishing License Holders (2021):</strong>", F2021, "<br>",
                    "<strong>Area (km²):</strong>", round(area_km2, 2)
                  ), HTML),
                  labelOptions = labelOptions(
                    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                    textsize = "15px",
                    direction = "auto"
                  ),
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(weight = 2, color = "white", bringToFront = TRUE))
  })
  
  # Handle clicks on map
  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
    clicked_id <- input$map_shape_click$id
    selected_area(clicked_id)
    drawn_polygon(NULL)
    
    # Update map to highlight selected area
    selected_shape <- postal_areas_simple[postal_areas_simple$CFSAUID == clicked_id, ]
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearGroup("highlight") %>%
      addPolygons(data = selected_shape,
                  fillColor = "yellow",
                  fillOpacity = 0.5,
                  weight = 2,
                  color = "black",
                  group = "highlight")
  })
  
  # Handle drawn polygons
  observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, {
    feature <- input$map_draw_new_feature
    
    if (feature$geometry$type == "Polygon") {
      drawn_polygon(feature)
      selected_area(NULL)
      
      tryCatch({
        coords <- lapply(feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]], function(pair) {
          c(as.numeric(pair[1]), as.numeric(pair[2]))
        })
        polygon_sf <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(do.call(rbind, coords))), crs = 4326)
        
        intersecting_areas <- postal_areas_simple[st_intersects(polygon_sf, spatial_index, sparse = FALSE)[1,], ]
        
        if (nrow(intersecting_areas) == 0) {
          area_summary <- "No postal areas selected. Try drawing a larger polygon."
        } else {
          total_area <- sum(intersecting_areas$area_km2, na.rm = TRUE)
          total_fish <- sum(intersecting_areas$F2021, na.rm = TRUE)
          area_summary <- paste(
            "<strong>Area Summary:</strong><br>",
            "Total Area:", round(total_area, 2), "km²<br>",
            "Fishing License Holders (2021):", total_fish
          )
        }
      }, error = function(e) {
        area_summary <- "Error processing polygon. Please try again."
        print(paste("Error:", e$message))
      })
      
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        clearControls() %>%
        addControl(
          html = tags$div(
            id = "summary",
            style = "background-color: white; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;",
            HTML(area_summary)
          ),
          position = "topright"
        )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_draw_deleted_features, {
    drawn_polygon(NULL)
    selected_area(NULL)
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearControls() %>%
      addControl(
        html = tags$div(
          id = "summary",
          style = "background-color: white; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;",
          HTML("<strong>No area selected.</strong>")
        ),
        position = "topright"
      )
  })
  
  # Create plot
  output$fishingPlot <- renderPlotly({
    area_id <- selected_area()
    polygon <- drawn_polygon()
    
    if (!is.null(area_id)) {
      data <- postal_areas_long[CFSAUID == area_id]
      title <- paste("Fishing License Holders in", area_id)
    } else if (!is.null(polygon)) {
      tryCatch({
        coords <- lapply(polygon$geometry$coordinates[[1]], function(pair) {
          c(as.numeric(pair[1]), as.numeric(pair[2]))
        })
        polygon_sf <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(do.call(rbind, coords))), crs = 4326)
        
        intersecting_areas <- postal_areas_simple[st_intersects(polygon_sf, spatial_index, sparse = FALSE)[1,], ]
        intersecting_cfsauids <- intersecting_areas$CFSAUID
        
        data <- postal_areas_long[CFSAUID %in% intersecting_cfsauids, 
                                  .(Lic_Num = sum(Lic_Num, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                                  by = Year]
        title <- "Fishing License Holders in Selected Area"
      }, error = function(e) {
        print(paste("Error in get_plot_data:", e$message))
        return(NULL)
      })
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    if (is.null(data)) return(NULL)
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Lic_Num)) +
      geom_col(fill = "lightblue") +
      geom_text(aes(label = Lic_Num), vjust = -3, color = "black", size = 4) +
      labs(title = title,
           y = "Number of License Holders",
           x = "Year") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 14), 
            axis.text.y = element_text( size = 14), 
            axis.title = element_text(size = 17))
    
    ggplotly(plot)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)

rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "./ShinyApp", appName = "XXX", account = "XXX")


Please boil down your code to a minimal reproducible example. Chances are, you'll identify or even fix some of the bugs (asset licence_data.rda not found, function leafletOutput not available) in the process.

It may not be the only problem, but setwd("./ShinyApp") is definitely not helping and isn't needed at all.

And unclear whether this is in the code you are trying to deploy, but remove the rsconnect::deployApp()
